# do you know why this block is so unusually small?

Tags: blockchain

i just stumbled upon this block in the blockchain:
https://blockchain.info/block/00000000000000000052fca516261b65a8a455f35f4c2f867acfb08069def3ec
why is it so small with so few transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Miners can include as many (under the block size limit of course) or as few transactions as they like in a block. There may not be any particular reason for a lower number of transactions, thats just up to whatever algorithm the miners used to select transactions to mine in that block